# Chrome extension overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to make a chrome extension, but there's a few things I don't understand, and when I looked it up, I always end up with opposite advices, and nothing I manage to make work, so I'm seeking for your help.

Here's an exemple of the features I'd like to cover :
Having an **overlay** I can show or hide with a **chrome hotkey**, on any page, containing the same text area, no matter which tab or page I'm in (I'm guessing I should use js to send the content of my text area into a variable global to every tabs or pages.
I've also included jquery, but have to include it in every html, don't know how to include it somewhere that I can use for each pages I make.

What I need :
- How to include an overlay
- How to define a chrome hotkey for your extension
- How to make global variable between every pages and tabs

Thanks

Comment: Please show us what you have tried?

Comment: For now, I'm not really far, all I've got working is an option where I can set or reset a username, and showing it when clicking on the extension button : https://github.com/NecroSyri/digiapp

Comment: I managed to find how to deal with hotkeys, using "commands" in the manifest, and a background page, with a switch inside this : chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've solved almost all my problems now :

manifest.json :

```
"commands": {
    "toggle-digivice": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Space"
      },
      "description": "Show or hide digivice"
    }
  },
  "background": {
    "page": "pages/background.html"
  }
```

background.js

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
  //alert(command);
  switch(command){
    case "toggle-digivice" :
      console.log("toggle");
      toggle_digivice();
    break;
  }
});

function toggle_digivice(){
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id,{file:"js/overlay.js"});
  });
}
```

overlay.js :

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<div id='overlay'>overlay.html</div>";
```

Now, I need to update my background overlay, and figure out how to call the content of my background to the innerHTML.